# calling DLL- function with python

Tags: python, c++, arrays, dll, struct

I was searching about 2 days of solution to problem with calling a function:

```
int  HG_GetProgList  (sHG_ProgSlot** list)
```

from DLL with python. sHG_ProgSlot is here a struct:

```
typedef struct       //---- data set of a 'program slot' in the RDS-coder
{
    char strname [9];  
    int       slot;      
    int      bytes;                       
    int     groups; 
    int      times;    
    int  next_slot;  
} sHG_ProgSlot;
```

the description of the function in dll is following:

```
RDSHG81300B_API int __stdcall  HG_GetProgList  (sHG_ProgSlot** list);
```

// The DLL contains an array of sHG_ProgSlot with all occupied 'program slots'.

// The entries are sorted by their slot number in ascending order.

// This function copies the pointer to this array to the function argument.

// (Use HG_GetNumberOfProgs() to get the array's length.)

// Input:  list - pointer to be set

// Output: 0= no error

I wrote the folllowing code:

```
class RDSCoderService(object):
    def GetProgramList(self, programList):
        getProgListFunction = self.RDS_Lib['HG_GetProgList]
        getProgListFunction.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(sHG_ProgSlot*60))]
        getProgListFunction.restype = ctypes.c_int
        return getProgListFunction(programList)

class sHG_ProgSlot(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("strname", ctypes.c_char*9),
                ("slot", ctypes.c_int),
                ("bytes", ctypes.c_int),
                ("groups", ctypes.c_int),
                ("times", ctypes.c_int),
                ("next_slot", ctypes.c_int)]
```

calling of function:

```
rds=RDSCoderService()
struct_p=ctypes.POINTER(sHG_ProgSlot)  #pointer to a structure type
arr_of_struct_pointer=struct_p*60      #array of pointers to a struct type of size 60
instance_array=arr_of_struct_pointer() # instance array
p_inst_array=ctypes.pointer(instance_array)# pointer to array
Message=rds.GetProgramList(p_inst_array) #calling of function
```

thank you for helping!

Comment: You haven't documented what happens during "calling of function" - how far does it get?  Also, "This function copies the pointer to this array to the function argument" - why are you doing this: `arr_of_struct_pointer=struct_p*60` and this `instance_array=arr_of_struct_pointer()`, when it sounds like you should be calling `rds.GetProgramList` with the address of a pointer for it to copy into, such as `struct_p`...?  Put another way, it doesn't sound like the function is going to copy all the data out into your python variables, rather - it just copies out the address of its own data.

Comment: the error message is following: in GetProgramList return getProgListFunction(programList) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_sHG_ProgSlot_Array_60 instance instead of LP_LP_sHG_ProgSlot_Array_60

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd have thought you wanted something like  `ptr_ptr = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(sHG_ProgSlot*60))()` / `Message=rds.GetProgramList(ptr_ptr)` / after which hopefully `ptr_ptr.contents` would address the data...

Comment: Thank you for helping, Tony D, here is code that works: myGroups = ctypes.c_void_p() Message = rds.GetProgramList(ctypes.byref(myGroups)) casted = ctypes.cast( myGroups, ctypes.POINTER(sHG_ProgSlot*60) )  GroupArray = ctypes.POINTER(sHG_ProgSlot*60) group_array = GroupArray.from_address(ctypes.addressof(myGroups)) for x in range(0,60): print '\n Slot:', x print 'sHG_ProgSlot.strname:' , group_array.contents[x].strname

Comment: Oh - congrats on solving it.  You can post that as an answer to your own question... easier to find for other people later....  Cheers.